# Removing a parent row if a specific value is found

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table without a specific class or ID, and I've like to remove all table rows that have links inside with a specific attribute value (href*=...) inside that table, or for that matter, anywhere on the web site. I can get rid of the links, but not the row that has that link inside it.
How can I do this with css? If not, then with jQuery or JS?

Comment: are you familiar with `.parent()` in jquery? There's a hint

Comment: yes, I am. I was hoping to use just css, but if I can't that's the way I'll have to go. So with jQuery would it be something like: $(link with  attribute of ...).parent (don't display it);...?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. The 2 answers below are basically the same thing. `$(link with attribute).parent().hide()` would hide the parent. `.closest()` is probably better cause your links may be nested. CSS alone - not that I know of. Though CSS is advancing impressively so such a thing may be possible in the future. who knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no CSS parent selector, so it's not possible with CSS alone.

You can do it with jQuery very easily though, using attribute selectors:

```
$('table a[href=SomethingSpecific]').closest('tr').remove();
```

Or, you could select all your anchors and filter them (quicker):

```
$('table a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href') == 'SomethingSpecific';
}).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to find the the table row which contains the link and then delete that row using the [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function:

```
$("a[href*=...]").closest("tr").remove();
```